# Is there a way to transfer a header to several worksheets?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I create the following header and want to apply it to several worksheets instead of writing the same code for every 16 worksheets. Is there a way to build a method for this and use it for all worksheets?

```
            // Create Worksheet
            var nf = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Station_1");
            // +15 worksheets...

            // Format Header
            nf.Cells["A1"].Value = "Login";
            nf.Cells["A2"].Value = "Password";
            nf.Cells["A3"].Value = "Date";
            nf.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

Comment: Loop over all worksheets, inserting your header at the specified location. Looking at your code. It should be very simple to refactor a seperate function for this. Just pass your function the workbook and your predefined header. Then it should insert the header into all sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose nf is of type `ExcelWorkSheet`. Add a method FormatHeader(ExcelWorkSheet ws) and call it with all your worksheets:

```cs
private void FormatHeader(ExcelWorkSheet ws)
{
    // Format Header
    ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Login";
    ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "Password";
    ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "Date";
    ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
}
```

Call it like this:

```cs
FormatHeader(package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Station_1"));
FormatHeader(package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Station_2"));
...
```

Comment: Perfect, works for me. The Method is FormatHeader(ExcelWorksheet ws) for me, because i'm using EPPLUS. Thank you!

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect that.